# Reverting @AppStorage when dismissing a preference view via cancel

Tags: swiftui, appstorage

Consider the following `PreferencesView` presented as a sheet:

```
struct PreferencesView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    @AppStorage("setting1") var setting1: Bool = true
    @AppStorage("setting2") var setting2: Bool = false
    @AppStorage("setting3") var setting3: Bool = false
    // many more

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Toggle("Setting 1", isOn: $setting1)
                Toggle("Setting 2", isOn: $setting2)
                Toggle("Setting 3", isOn: $setting3)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Preferences")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        reset()

                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Save") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func reset() {
        // what do I put here?
    }
}
```

If the user hits cancel, I'd like the value of the settings be set back to when the sheet opened. I could add separate `initialSetting1`, etc properties, and then in the `reset` function add `setting1 = initialSetting1`. But with a lot of settings that becomes tedious.

Is there another way?

Comment: don't save it to app storage on change, instead have internal @State variables for the toggle, and assign their values to `@AppStorage` variables when user clicks Save. That way you don't need to "revert", you simply won't save new values until the user told your app to do so.

Comment: @timbretimbre That sounds like a good idea. But how do I assign the current value in `@Appstorage` to a `@State` variable?

Comment: And vice versa, can't figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: You could use UserDefaults directly instead of the property wrapper if you want more control of how/when to save your settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Load current settings using `onAppear`
- Use local `@State` to bind to a toggle
- Save current values from `@State` to settings when user presses Save button.

Like this:

```
struct PreferencesView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    @AppStorage("setting1") var setting1: Bool = true
    @AppStorage("setting2") var setting2: Bool = false
    @AppStorage("setting3") var setting3: Bool = false
    
    // Initial value doesn't matter, will be overwritten
    @State var currentSetting1: Bool = false
    @State var currentSetting2: Bool = false
    @State var currentSetting3: Bool = false
    // many more

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                // Change internal state, not settings
                Toggle("Setting 1", isOn: $currentSetting1)
                Toggle("Setting 2", isOn: $currentSetting2)
                Toggle("Setting 3", isOn: $currentSetting3)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Preferences")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        // No need to do anything here
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Save") {
                        // Save current internal state to settings
                        setting1 = currentSetting1
                        setting2 = currentSetting2
                        setting3 = currentSetting3
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear() {
                // Load settings
                currentSetting1 = setting1
                currentSetting2 = setting2
                currentSetting3 = setting3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution using `@State` and `onAppear`. I am using the suggestion from  
Joakim Danielson though, to interact with `UserDefaults` directly.